# Como publicar tweets con media

Tags: python, tweepy

Tengo un programa que publica imágenes con pie de página que funciona al 100% en windows, pero al subirlo al servidor en Linux, me devuelve un error:

```
'API' object has no attribute 'update_with_media'
```

Mi código es este:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, timeout=60)
api.update_with_media("img.png","caption")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución y la comparto para próximos usuarios.

Parece que han actualizado tweepy recientemente, yo tenía la versión 3.10.0 y parece que hay hasta la 4.5, en la nueva desaparecen varias funciones aunque podéis encontrarlo todo aquí: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.3.0/api.html

Personalmente, he cambiado mi versión a la anterior para evitar futuros problemas.

Espero que sirva!!